# Point symbols in R

Tags: r, plot, symbols, draw

There are 25 symbols defined by 'pch' paramter in the points function.

How can I draw more than these 25 symbols

Thanks

Comment: this wont answer your question, but if for some reason you need to plot >25 symbols, start coloring them to increase the diversity

Comment: If you need more than 25 symbols in a plot you need to rethink your problem.

Comment: Obviously, the question was not about adding 25+ symbols, it was "what other custom symbols can I make". Given that the given set of 25 is very, very clunky. I really wish R can improve on the symbol design!

Answer (score 9):

You can see all the options for a given font using code like:

```
plot( 0:15, 0:15, type='n' )
points( (0:255)%% 16, (0:255) %/% 16, pch=0:255, font=5 )
```

Change the font= to different numbers for different options.  There are a couple more options using the symbols function.  If you want even more then check out the my.symbols function in the TeachingDemos package (I am the author of `my.symbols` and most of the TeachingDemos package).  There are several symbols available already and it gives an option for creating your own custom symbols, so there really is no limit.

Comment: authorship disclosure please :p

Comment: @MichaelChirico, are you referring to the code with `plot` and `points`?  If so, who do you think deserves the authorship credit?  I fully admit that I am not the first to come up with the above code, but I don't know who came up with it first or a reference, will be happy to include them if you can point it out.  Or do you want me to admit that I am the author of `my.symbols` and the TeachingDemos package?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the basic plotting and drawing functions to devise your own symbols. Use 'lines' or 'segments' for drawing lines and 'polygon' for filled areas. So you might have a function called 'littleHouse' that takes x,y for the centre and w and h for width and height, then you would do something like:

```
for(i in 1:nrows(data)){
 di = data[i,]
 littleHouse(di$x,di$y,di$w,di$h)
}
```

Being any more specific is probably a waste of time unless you've got anything specific in mind. You can't do it via the pch parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You just can't... only this set is implemented. Some option is to use character vectors (eg. `pch=c('a','b','c')`) to get points marked by `a`s, `b`s, ... -- this extends the set to about 60 (with numbers), but does not look too well.