# How to fill a single 'pch' point on the plot with two-colours?

Tags: r, plot, pch

If you take the code below, how can you change the filling of the third diamond, so it will be half-black, half-white? The solution should apply with any colors.

```
data <- c(1,2,3)
plot(data, pch=c(23,18,23), cex=c(2.5,3,2.5))
```

Comment: Interesting question, newer thought about that...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `pch` characters are actual font symbols, so you will be limited to what is available in your fonts. Another alternative is to use the primitive plotting commands to make your own "symbols". This is very flexible, although there can be issues with resizing, etc., when mixing the two methods. This method is implemented in the nice `my.symbols()` example:

```
require(TeachingDemos)

bwDiamond <- function() {
    plot.new()
    polygon(c(0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0), c(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5), lty=1)
    polygon(c(0.25, 0.5, 1, 0.75, 0.25), c(0.25, 0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.25), col=1)
}

data <- c(1,2,3)

dev.new(width=4, height=4)
plot(data, type='n')
points(data[1:2], pch=c(23,18), cex=c(2.5,3))
my.symbols(data[3], data[3], symb=bwDiamond, symb.plots=TRUE, inches=0.22)
```

[image]

See also this Q/A: [Point symbols in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739366/point-symbols-in-r)

Comment: Perfect, thank you @John . However, I can see how it works very well with polygons, but how would you deal with half-color filled circle points?

Comment: @GeekOnAcid Heh...good point. I guess you could fake it as a polygon, but it'd be nice if there was a way to do it with only 3 anchors. I don't know of one though.

Answer (score 1):

@JohnColby : Ok, here is a way to draw a half-coloured circle point, using `grid.semicircle` from `lodplot` package. It's not such tidy solution as yours with polygons, but it does the job:

```
 require(lodplot)
 dev.new(width=4,height=4)
 plot(1:3,type="n")
 grid.semicircle(100,150,10,5)#left circle on plot below
 grid.semicircle(100,150,10,5,side=3,col=1)
 grid.semicircle(200,150,10,5,side=2)#right circle on plot below
 grid.semicircle(200,150,10,5,side=4,col=1)
```

[image: Half-circles plot example]

Comment: Nice find! That semicircle function will come in handy.