# create floating pie charts with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

Currently I am working on report with a floating pie chart as one of the plots. Currently I use the plotrix package to plot this pie chart. But since I use ggplot2 for all the other plots, the pie plot looks different. So I'm trying to create the plot using ggplot2. Currently I have two issues:

1. The ggplot pie charts are plotted on a polar coordination system. I want to plot multiple pie charts on Cartesian coordination system. At the moment I do not know how to do this.
2. I want to be able to control the pie radius on the Cartesian coordination system.

Here is the code I currently use:

```
library("plotrix")
plot(1:5, type="n", xlab="x", ylab="y")
floating.pie(2, 3, c(1,3,5), radius=0.5)
floating.pie(4, 2, c(2,4), radius=0.2)
floating.pie(4.5, 4, c(3,2,5,1), radius=0.3)
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233077/r-how-to-overlay-pie-charts-on-dots-in-a-scatterplot-in-r ; also, this conversation http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/b1f81cf870202e2c/f1a60b0c16a2f62a?pli=1 which suggests that `geom_pie` (or `geom_wedge` as suggested by Hadley Wickham) don't yet exist ...

Comment: Thanks, I think my request is not feasible at this moment. I just keep using the plotrix package.

Comment: In this blog post I found a nice solution: http://ygc.name/2015/08/31/subview/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Pie charts by definition use polar coordinates.  You could overlay some pie charts on another graph that used Cartesian coordinates but it would probably be awful.  In fact, pie charts are mostly awful anyway, so be careful what you wish for.
2. An example on the `coord_polar` page.

The important bit in that code is specifying that radius maps to the "y" aesthetic.

```
 df <- data.frame(
   variable = c("resembles", "does not resemble"),
   value = c(80, 20)
 )
ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "yellow")) + 
  coord_polar("y", start = 2 * pi / 3) +    #<- read this line!
  ggtitle("Pac man")
```

Comment: I agree, pie charts are mostly awful. But with only two pie parts I think it's just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, there is a package called `scatterpie` based on `ggfore` solving the problem.

It's on cran, and you can see the examples [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterpie/vignettes/scatterpie.html)

Comment: IME scatterpie is very fiddly. Being forced to use `coord_fixed` in particular is a tremendous hindrance.