# How to draw a pie chart in given position of another plot?

Tags: r, plot

I wonder how to draw a pie chart **in given position** of another plot.

I know how to put two plots in the same figure, using

```
plot(...)
line(...)
```

But this seems not working for pie chart. And I also want to specify where to draw the pie chart.

Could you please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try `floating.pie` from the `plotrix` package or `Rgraphviz::pieGlyph` ... also see

- [plotting pie graphs on map in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368180/plotting-pie-graphs-on-map-in-ggplot)
- [create floating pie charts with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684371/create-floating-pie-charts-with-ggplot)
- [R: How to overlay pie charts on 'dots' in a scatterplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233077/r-how-to-overlay-pie-charts-on-dots-in-a-scatterplot-in-r)
- `library(sos); findFn("pie chart")`