# ERROR: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r, analytics, rstudio, pie-chart

I have a dataset which has multiple longitude and latitude of different places in the UK. I am trying to use those figured to create multiple pie charts on the map. Whats essential is just making a pie chart on the map. NOTE: I can make a single pie chart if i hardcode the latitude and longitude.

Code:

```
floating.pie(xpos = area$longditude,  ypos = area$Latitude,x=1,  radius=0.2, col="orange")
```

Area:

```
area <- sqlQuery(con, "SELECT top 3 geo.Latitude, geo.longditude FROM dbo.[Geography]")
```

The dataset is:

```
55.9500, 3.1833
54.8659, -2.3522
54.0167, 2.6333
53.5667, 1.2000
52.8311, 1.3278
52.5000, 1.8333
52.3555, -1.1743
51.5000, 51.5000
51.4833, 3.1833
51.3167, 0.5000
50.9600, -3.2200
```

The error i am getting is:

```
Warning messages:
1: In cos(t2p) * radius + xpos :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In sin(t2p) * yradius + ypos :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Note: Using all of the above code, i dont get seperate piecharts at all. not sure how to do this, help please.
As an example view 
    [plotting pie graphs on map in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368180/plotting-pie-graphs-on-map-in-ggplot)

What you see in the webpaghe is what i want i ve got it working nearly, just need to know how to tell R to differentiate those values i provide using Area and to plot them correctly as a single pie chart.

Comment: Did you perhaps mispell `longitude`? (e.g. you have `area$longditude`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to plot multiple float pie charts, but I had to use an infamous `for` loop.

```
area1<-data.frame(Longitude = c(10,30, 50), 
Latitude = c(5, 25, 50))

plot(0:100,type="n",main="Floating Pie test",xlab="",ylab="",axes=FALSE)
for(i in 1:length(area1$Longitude)){
    floating.pie(xpos = area1$Longitude[i],  
    ypos = area1$Latitude[i],edges = 200, x=1,  radius=10, col="orange")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just want to point out that the `xpos` and `ypos` values are the coordinates of the plot area, so you'll probably have to convert the coordinate values to ones that translate to the map.