# Plotting multiple boxplots on single map

Tags: r, maps, spatial, boxplot, ggmap

I have a dataset containing the location information (lat, long) and annual contribution of 73 stations. Here is a snippet of the dataset-

```
       Station Year Contribution     Lat      Long
1  USC00020750 1964     6.381039 36.6778 -110.5411
2  USC00020750 1965    10.638735 36.6778 -110.5411
3  USC00020750 1966     5.568942 36.6778 -110.5411
4  USC00020750 1967     8.214286 36.6778 -110.5411
5  USC00020750 1968    13.981570 36.6778 -110.5411
6  USC00020750 1969     8.607199 36.6778 -110.5411
7  USC00020750 1970    12.183436 36.6778 -110.5411
8  USC00020750 1971    11.382114 36.6778 -110.5411
9  USC00020750 1972     6.647583 36.6778 -110.5411
10 USC00020750 1973     4.921077 36.6778 -110.5411
11 USC00020750 1974    13.102512 36.6778 -110.5411
12 USC00020750 1975    14.181487 36.6778 -110.5411
13 USC00020750 1976     7.141769 36.6778 -110.5411
14 USC00020750 1977     7.267267 36.6778 -110.5411
15 USC00020750 1978    10.701754 36.6778 -110.5411
16 USC00020750 1979    14.981949 36.6778 -110.5411
17 USC00020750 1980    14.671654 36.6778 -110.5411
18 USC00020750 1981     6.272401 36.6778 -110.5411
19 USC00020750 1982     6.117234 36.6778 -110.5411
20 USC00020750 1983     6.985224 36.6778 -110.5411
```

...

```
         Station Year Contribution     Lat      Long
3630 USW00093129 1993    16.330451 37.7086 -113.0944
3631 USW00093129 1994    15.115512 37.7086 -113.0944
3632 USW00093129 1995     8.773946 37.7086 -113.0944
3633 USW00093129 1996     8.362573 37.7086 -113.0944
3634 USW00093129 1997     7.858156 37.7086 -113.0944
3635 USW00093129 1998     7.174763 37.7086 -113.0944
3636 USW00093129 1999     6.158664 37.7086 -113.0944
3637 USW00093129 2000    18.498896 37.7086 -113.0944
3638 USW00093129 2001    12.168397 37.7086 -113.0944
3639 USW00093129 2002     7.325103 37.7086 -113.0944
3640 USW00093129 2003    10.321489 37.7086 -113.0944
3641 USW00093129 2004     7.204181 37.7086 -113.0944
3642 USW00093129 2005    11.059623 37.7086 -113.0944
3643 USW00093129 2006     8.206687 37.7086 -113.0944
3644 USW00093129 2007     7.790078 37.7086 -113.0944
3645 USW00093129 2008    12.083333 37.7086 -113.0944
3646 USW00093129 2009     7.763713 37.7086 -113.0944
3647 USW00093129 2010    11.049468 37.7086 -113.0944
3648 USW00093129 2011     7.131333 37.7086 -113.0944
3649 USW00093129 2012     5.926401 37.7086 -113.0944
3650 USW00093129 2013     9.509202 37.7086 -113.0944
```

I want to make the boxplot of the annual contribution (`boxplot(Contribution~Year,data=data)`) for a set of stations (let's say 3) on a spatial map. I am aware of methods to plot multiple boxplots in one graph ([Plot multiple boxplot in one graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604439/plot-multiple-boxplot-in-one-graph)) but I am not sure how to display them on a map. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: not easy task. package ggsubplot used to make it possible but it's not active anymore. Just look on SO and you will see some of the problems with this package. this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368180/plotting-pie-graphs-on-map-in-ggplot might help bit seems a bit complicated