# Can you combine a geom_bar pie over a geom_point plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, geom-bar, geom-point

Is there a way to plot `geom_pie` over a `geom_point` plot? with a shared Variable (here: Location)

I have seen people do pies over maps [plotting pie graphs on map in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368180/plotting-pie-graphs-on-map-in-ggplot)

But I was wondering if there is some package or function which allows you to do it?

Here is my data and two current plots:

```
data_point <- data.frame(
  Location=(1:7),
  Var1=c(13,8, 6,5,4,2,1),
  Var2 = c(7,8,9,10,11,12,13))

data_pie <- data.frame(
  Location=rep(1:7,5),
  Group= c(rep("A",7),rep("B",7),rep("C",7),rep("D",7),rep("E",7)),
  value=c(45.59,63.56,66.47,58.60,67.28,44.45,9.22,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,4.14,37.81,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.04,
0.03,25.15,34.58,52.86,35.61,24.66,26.13,18.98,12.71,6.61,2,1,9,15,14,14,12))

a<-ggplot(data_point, aes(Var1, Var2, label=1:7)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3, stroke = 2)+
  theme_classic()
b<- ggplot(data_pie, aes(x="", y=value, fill=Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  facet_wrap(~Location)+ scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2")
ggarrange(a,b, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Desired plot:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried out the [scatterpie](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterpie/vignettes/scatterpie.html) package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea with `geom_scatterpie` from the `scatterpie` package:

**Join Data**

```
df <- data_pie %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Location,
              names_from = Group, 
              values_from =  value) %>% 
  left_join(data_point, by = "Location")
```

**Code**

```
library(scatterpie)

ggplot() +
  geom_scatterpie(data = df, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2,
                      group = Location), 
                  cols = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
```

**Plot**
[image]

Comment: Yes this works, didn't know about the package. Thanks! However, can you run it with this? The pie seem to have a radius/angle problem? I do not know what is going on

Comment: ```data_point <- data.frame(
  Location=(1:7),
  Var1=c(1,0.96,0.67,0.78,0.55,0.3,0.26),
  Var2 = c(7,8,9,10,11,12,13))```

Comment: I have changed Var1

Comment: It seems that the roundness of the pies depend on the ratio of the axis - one unit on the x-axis has to bee the same length as one unit on the y-axis. By adding `+ coord_fixed()` to the code you may achieve the ratio of 1 annd round pies. But that will make your plot tall and narrow - in my eyes the plot is now hard to read.

Comment: As a quick workaround of this problem you can transform your x values by multipling with 10 and relabel the labels. `df2 <- df %>% mutate(Var3 = Var1*10)` and `ggplot() + geom_scatterpie(data = df2, aes(x = Var3 , y = Var2, group = Location), cols = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), pie_scale = 3) + scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) x/10) + coord_fixed()`

Comment: Awesome, it actually works bettie with *100 :)